# Change Bootstrap number of columns in grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If I only have **9 columns**, but I want to spread them 100% of the div.  How can this be done?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">NSW</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">VIC</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">QLD</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">WA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">SA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">TAS</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">ACT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">NT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">NZ</div>   
</div>
```

And then when I shrink the page, or a mobile device. Like a table, how can these be put as so?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under NSW</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under VIC</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under QLD</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under WA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under SA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under TAS</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under ACT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under NT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 grid-head">under NZ</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You should use col-lg-12.

Comment: Why not have them all in  1 column and use a container using display: flex; easier to target with css that way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216361/bootstrap-3-0-grid-with-less-than-12-columns

Comment: hmm.. im not aware of that, I will play around with it?

Comment: @Valius79 I don't want just 1 column.. i want 9 columns, spread to the whole width, instead of being 3 columns short. and then when i use a smaller display, the text under nsw etc, should stack under the header? if that makes sense..

Comment: @user2639176 Here's a link to a complete guide on how to use flexbox, it could be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Another approach would be to divide the 9 items into 3-3-3. Each set of 3 gets col-*-4. This way, internally, they can be col-*-4. Check this out[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8VhHy1sIfiq5LvmbCLrY?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is divided the 9 items into groups of three.

This way, you give each group something along the lines of `col-*-4`.

So your **HTML** will look like

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 PA">
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">NSW</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">VIC</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">QLD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4  PA">
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">WA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">SA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">TAS</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4  PA">
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">ACT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">NT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 grid-head">NZ</div> 
  </div>
```

I've added the `PA` class to remove any padding to grid-head.
After cleaning up the CSS a bit and removing any padding, you'll get the required condition.

Here is a [**working demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8VhHy1sIfiq5LvmbCLrY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can also [customize your Bootstrap's file](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) by changing the number of columns.

The attribute to be changed is [`@grid-columns`](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), set 9 in your case.

Then you just have to [download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#download) your customized Bootstrap's file and replace default by this one. Note it will apply `@grid-columns = 9` in your whole page.